Question about Rudra meaning
I found this extracts on Wikipedia , Rudra page :
Rudra is praised as the "mightiest of the mighty".[8] Rudra means "who eradicates problems from their roots"
On the quotation where is written "who eradicates problems from their roots" the citation on Wikipedia is missing.
Where is coming from ?

my question is searching scripture quotations related to this sentence since "wikipedia" does not provide them. is it false?

related: https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/essay/charaka-samhita-and-sushruta-samhita/d/doc1147038.html#note-e-207931

Shayanacharya gives multiple meanings for रुद्र (Rudra) in his Rgveda-BhAshya for Sukta 1.114.1 which is as follows:
इ॒मा रु॒द्राय॑ त॒वसे॑ कप॒र्दिने॑ क्ष॒यद्वी॑राय॒ प्र भ॑रामहे म॒तीः ।
यथा॒ शमस॑द्द्वि॒पदे॒ चतु॑ष्पदे॒ विश्वं॑ पु॒ष्टं ग्रामे॑
अ॒स्मिन्न॑नातु॒रम् ॥ इमा रुद्राय तवसे कपर्दिने क्षयद्वीराय प्र भरामहे
मतीः । यथा शमसद्द्विपदे चतुष्पदे विश्वं पुष्टं ग्रामे अस्मिन्ननातुरम् ॥


“We offer these praises to the mighty Rudra, with the braided hair,
the destroyer of heroes, in order that health may be enjoyed by bipeds
and quadrupeds, and that all beings in this village may be (well)
nourished and exempt from disease.”

One of the meanings of Rudra given by Shayanacharya is:
रुत् संसारख्यं दुःखम् । तत् द्रावयति अपगमयति विनाशयतीति रुद्रः |


He dissolves / removes / destroys रुत् (Rut) i.e., the sorrow of Samsara.

In the above verse, three words are used for emphasis - द्रावयति (DrAvayati) अपगमयति (apagamayati) विनाशयतीति (vinAshayati) which mean dissolve, remove, and destroy respectively. This essentially means eradicating sorrows from the root.

" the destroyer of heroes" - does this include hari?

'apagamayati' means 'remover of mayā'?

The prayer is unto Lord Rudra and He's the ultimate Hero in the spirit of this verse. There's no mention of Lord Hari here. Yes, He certainly can remove maya.

i wonder if vinAshayati is related to a configuration(vinyaas) or mental state perhaps...

No, vinasha is a common word across Indian languages which is derived from Sanskrit. It simply means destruction.

@blue_ego There is no difference between Hari and har so can it include Hari??

no difference but then who is lonely wihout shree? @ShriHarivansh

They seem to do different lilas but it has been said it bhagwat mahapuran that there is no difference in Hari, Har and Brahma ji @blue_ego

is there a relation between रुत् and marut?

Your question: Rudra doesn't just eradicate problems but does so from its ROOT.
So, what is the Root of all problems? It is mortality, because we have limited TIME and that time will degrade our bodies, our life source BREATH will stop someday. Not just us, but all our loved ones as well. We don't want to CRY, we don't want our HEALTH to degrade. We are burdened by our SIN (PAAPA) which will come and create problems. And finally, we don't have the KNOWLEDGE to do any of this.
So what is the ROOT? it's PAAPA.
What is running away from us that we can't stop? TIME
What do we care most? Health and medicine for ourselves and our Loved Ones. So that we don't cry
What do we want to KNOW all this? Someone who can give us Knowledge of Immortality, remove our Sins, give us Health, and not make us cry.
Hope the readers are ready for a lengthy list of references.

सोमारुद्रा वि वृहतं विषूचीम् अमीवा या नो गयम् आविवेश । बाधेथां दूरं
निरृतिम् पराचैः॒ कृतं चिद् एनः प्र मुमुक्तम् अस्मत् ॥१॥ Cast away
(वृह), and separate us (विषूची) from all bondages/sicknesses (अमीवा)
from us and our families (गय) O Soma and Rudra (सोमारुद्रा ), drive
away (पराचै) afar ( दूरं) our pain/suffering (बाध) and
death/destruction (निरृति) liberate us ( मुक्त ) from those (अस्मत्)
even if (चिद्) they are committed (कृत) sins/papa ( एनः) 7.42.1
सोमारुद्रा यु॒वमेतान्यस्मे विश्वा तनूषु भेषजानि धत्तम् |अव स्यतं
मु॒ञ्चतं यन्नो अस्ति तनूषु बद्धं कृ॒तमेनो अस्मत् ॥२॥ O Soma and Rudra
(सोमारुद्रा ) always bestow (ध – धत) upon us (यु॒वम +एतानि +अन्य्) the
cure, with all (विश्वा) your medicines (भेषजानि) tied to our bodily
realm (तनू) | liberate us/untie us (मुञ्चति) from those (अस्मत्) we
have (अस्ति) done(कृ॒त) , which (य) are connected (बद्ध) with our
physical/bodily realm (तनू) 7.42.2. Please note: (यु॒वम +एतानि +अन्य्)
means all these for us, used as 2nd person pronoun. Soma and Rudra!
Bring all these medicines to our bodies! Untie, get rid of from us the
sin committed that is bound to our bodies.
मा नो रुद्र तक्मना मा विषेण मा नः सं -स्रा दिव्येनाग्निना 11.2.26
Rudra (रुद्र) untie (सं -स्रा) for us (नो ) those diseases (तक्म – ना
) and those vicious poisons (विषेण मा न) and from the divine fire
(दिव्येनाग्निना) Please note : सं -स्रा = untie where as सं-स्राव =
flow together
Atharva Veda 7.42.1-2


अपाम सोमममृता अभू॒मागन्म ज्योतिरविदाम देवान् किं नू॒नमस्मान्कृणवदरातिः
किमु धू॒र्तिरमृत मर्त्य॑स्य RV 8.48.3 We consumed/attained the Divine
Soma, we are now immortal, We have attained the
brilliance/light/wisdom, we have witnessed the divine, what have we
(the ignorant mortals/suffering/illusions) to fear, being that
immortal?
He is “the resort/lord to all hymns/songs”, He is “the resort/lord of
all yajñá/sacrifice”, and “He is bliss”. Rudras as the family of
immortals possessing amṛta/soma and this Soma is the home to Supreme
Truth (ṛtasya). RV 1.43
Rig Veda 8.48.3 / 1.43
SOURCE LINK
यद्यू॒यं पृ॑श्निमातरो॒ मर्ता॑सः॒ स्यात॑न ।स्तो॒ता वो॑ अ॒मृतः॑ स्यात् ॥
1.38.4 Though you (यद्यू॒यं), who were born to Prishni (पृ॑श्नि :मातरो॒ = cow of knowledge), are mortal (मर्ता॑सः॒), those who sing
your hymns become immortal (not physical immortality, but a state of
eternal consciousness: satyam. (This hymn is explained in detail in
Satarudriya Yagna later in Sukla Yajur Veda)
एवा बभ्रो वृषभ चेकितान यथा देव न हृणीषे न हंसि । हवनश्रुन्नो रुद्रेह
बोधि बृहद्वदेम विदथे सुवीराः ॥ Certainly (एवा ), oh mighty
chief/overlord (वृषभ ) with tawny/reddish hue (बभ्रो ), henceforth we
proclaim (यथा ) the all-knowing/omniscient Divine (चेकितान देव) ,
forgive us/not punish us (न हृणी), be not angry (न हंसि ), hear our
oblation (हवनश्रुन्न) and direct us on this occasion (विदथ), oh
powerful (बृहद्व) Rudra of perfect wisdom/speech (बोधि), bless us with
noble and heroic successors (सुवीरा) || 2.33.15
Source LINK
त्र्यंबकं यजामहे सुगंधिं पुष्टिवर्धनं । उर्वारुकमिव
बंधनान्मृत्योर्मुक्षीय मामृतात् ॥ 7.59.12 Oh Triambaka (3
eyes/seasons), we offer our oblation (यजाम), nourish us (पुष्टि) and
bestow us (वर्ध) into the trance of fragrance (सुगंधिं) | May you
untie our bonds (बंधना) like a ripened gourd fruit (उर्वारु) unties
itself from the stem, and take us beyond death (मृत्यु) and deplete
(र्मु–क्षीय) our compulsions (र्मु) and take us (मा) into the immortal
state (अ॒मृत॑) (मृत्यु + मोक्ष (मोह+क्षेय) + मा-अमृतात्) Please note:
सुगंधिं does not mean physical perfume, but the nostalgia one feels
upon experiencing a certain sound or fragrance or taste. So it means
to bestow us into the sweetness of imagining Thy Divinity during the
transcendental states of dhyana/dharana. र्क्षीय: means to deplete,
and र्मुक्षीय means to deplete our moha/compulsions arising out of
Avidya. मा is also an Adj & Conj use as negative as “not”.
Rig Veda 7.59


द्योजातं प्रपद्यामि सद्योजाताय वै नमो नमः । भवेभवे नातिभवे भवस्व माम्
। भवोद्भवाय नमः ॥ 10.17.35.17 Oh Sadyojatha (सद्योजात = Rudra’s west
side face) I surrender on to you (प्रपद्यामि) I bow to you again and
again (नमो नमः) | Existance after Existance (भवेभवे = life after life)
not more do I seek to comeback (नाति-भवे) liberate me from this
repetation (भवस्-व माम्) oh one who is beyond existance (भवोद्भवाय) my
salutations to thy (नमः)
स एव काले भुवनस्य गोप्ता विश्वाधिपः सर्वभूतेषु गूढः। यस्मिन्युक्ता
ब्रह्मर्षयो देवताश्च तमेवं ज्ञात्वा मृत्युपाशांश्छिनत्ति॥4.15 He in
Time (स एव काले ) the overlord/caretaker (गोप्ता) who is the one sole
ruler (विश्वाधिपः) of all celestial mansions/creation (भुवनस्य) hidden
indweller (गूढः) of all beings (सर्वभूतेषु ) | In whom (यस्मिन् ) the
exalted sages who attained Brahmi states (ब्रह्मर्षयो) the divine
beings (देवताश्च) merge into (युक्ताः ) by knowing him (तमेवं
ज्ञात्वा) are released/cuts/free oneself (चिनत्ति) from the tethers of
Death (मृत्युपाशां).
Kṛṣṇa Yajur Veda Taittirīya Āraṇyaka 10.17-21 & Svetasvatara Upaniṣhad
4.15
या ते रुद्र शिवा तनूः शिवा विश्वाह भेषजी | शिवा रुद्रस्य भेषजी तया
नोमृड जीवसे 4.5.10.2 “yate Rudra Śivā tanuhu Śivā Vishvaha Bheshaji |
Śivā Rudrasya Bheshaji “ Oh Rudra you are of Śiva (auspicious)
body/form. As Śivā to your the medicine/cure (भेष॒जी) to all entirety,
you are eternal cure to all worldly ailments (विश्वाहभेषजी ) With that
(तया) auspicious form (शिवा) you are the cure to our crying/suffering
(रुद्रस्य) (samsara/avidya) medicine (भेषजी) is the relief to us all
(न) jivas (जीवसे all living entities) comfort/solace (मृड).
Kṛṣṇa Yajur Veda Taittirīya Saṃhitā 4.5.10.2


The mind or Antahkarana (मनः), present in all beings (प्रजासु ), is
fortified and steadfast (धृतिश्च) in making conscious effort and not
being compulsive or ruled by desires (चेतो), is endowed with wisdom
and intelligence (ज्ञानमुत), without (ऋते ) which (यस्मात्) one cannot
act (न कर्म- क्रिय). It is this inner fire/source which is the
immortal self (अमृतं ); may it be filled with my auspicious resolve
(शिवसंकल्पमस्तु). 3
That (येनेदं) mental framework (मनः) is the one that experiences
(परिगृहीत) the past (भू॒तं), the current/present (भुवनं), and the
future (भविष्यत). It is the immortal (अमृतेन), all-knowing,
all-comprehending (सर्वम्) inner self (तन्म – येन). It is the inner
fire and source (यज्ञ), it encompasses (स्ता॒यते) seven (सप्त) inner
priests performing the real sacrifice (होता). May it be filled with my
auspicious resolve (शिवसंकल्पमस्तु) 4
In which (यस्मिन्) the Rig, Sama, and Yajur Veda (ऋग् साम यजूँ॑षि )
are established (प्रतिष्ठिता) like the spikes of a chariot wheel
(रथ-नाभाविवाराः) so that knowledge is linked with all beings
(सर्व-मोतं प्रजानं), may that inner self (तन्मे) be filled with my
auspicious resolve (शिवसंकल्पमस्तु) 5
Rig Veda Baskala Shakha Khila Sukta 33 / Sukla Yajur Veda Kanva Shakha
33


ॐ नमो भगवते रुद्राय विष्णवे मृत्युर्मे पाहि॥ प्राणानां ग्रन्थिरसि
रुद्रो मा विशान्तकः। तेनान्नेनाप्यायस्व॥ AUM (ॐ =Pranava), salutations
(नमो ) oh Divine Rudra (भगवते रुद्राय), I surrender/save me (पाहि)
from eternal recurring death (विष्णवे मृत्युर्मे); Oh Rudra, you are
the vital force (प्राणानां) that connects (ग्रन्थि) us all (मा) and
you are the cure/an end (अन्तक) to all ill and poison (विश) that
corrupts. Hence (तेन), bestow your grace upon us in full (अप्याय+स्व)
in various aspects of life (अन्नेन).
Sri Rudram Kṛṣṇa Yajur Veda Namakam Closing hymn
Source Links

Let's come to UPANISHADs now:

या ते रुद्र शिवा तनूरघोराऽपापकाशिनी।तया नस्तनुवा शंतमया
गिरिशन्ताभिचाकशीहि॥3.5 You (या) Rudra of Auspicious (शिवा) body (तनू),
and of fierce form (अघोरा) resident of highest place (गिरिशन्त) with
your brilliant design/thought (अभिचा +काश्) which removes our avidya
and karmic cycle of pāpa (अ-पापकाशिनी ) make us (नः) realize our
blissful clam self(शंतमया + तनू  +तया ) ततः परं ब्रह्मपरं बृहन्तं
यथानिकायं सर्वभूतेषु गूढम्‌।विश्वस्यैकं परिवेष्टितारमीशं तं
ज्ञात्वाऽमृता भवन्ति॥3.7 Henceforth/moreover, further than (ततः परं)
Greatness known to us/our personal God (बृहन्त) is Brahman/infinite
that is further/superior (ब्रह्म+परं ) thought each enjoyed their own
bodies/individuality (यथानिकायम्) He is the indweller hidden in all
(सर्व+भूतेषु+गूढम् ) he along encompasses all entirety and is its
authority (विश्वस्य+ एकं+ परिवेष्टितारम + ईशाम् ) knowing/realizing
that one becomes amṛta/immortal (ज्ञात्वा+अमृताः ).
Svetasvatara Upaniṣhad 3.5, 3.7
SOURCE LINK


कतमे रुद्रा इति दशेमे पुरुषे प्राणा आत्मैकादशस्ते॥ There (इति) are
the types of Rudras (रुद्रा) that enter the Purusha/being (पुरुषे),
ten are the Pranas (प्राणा) that enter the 5 Karmindriyas and 5
Jnanindriyas and the 11th (एकादश) is the Atman/self/mind (आत्म)
Br̥hadāraṇyaka Upaniṣad 3.9.4


Rudra is the pure, spontaneous self-experience which is the one
consciousness that dwells in all substances. It is the seed of all
seeds, He is Prana, He is Atman, it is the essence of this world
appearance, it is the greatest of actions. It is the cause of all
causes and it is the essence in all beings, though in fact it does not
cause anything nor is it the concept of being, and therefore cannot be
conceived. Yoga Vaśiṣṭham 6.1.36 Swami Venkateshananda

Similarly, Śrī Adi Śankaracharya said:

अन्नपूर्णे सदापूर्णे शङ्करप्राणवल्लभे । ज्ञानवैराग्यसिद्ध्यर्थं
भिक्षां देहि च पार्वति ॥ ११॥ Devi Annapurnae, you are forever
whole/full, oh beloved eternal companion of Śankara. Bestow upon me as
alms the Jnana (wisdom/core essence) that leads to the meaningful
outcome of Vairāgya (detachment from desires and compulsions), oh
daughter of mountains, Pārvatī.
Annapurāstakam by Śrī Adi Śankaracharya

Rudra is TIME Source LINK
Rudra who makes us CRY and removes our CRY Source LINK
Independent Divinity holding the elixir of immortality RV5.58,TS4.5 and healing medicines RV1.114.5 Source LINK

if PAAPA is the root, does this mean PAAPA is the root of the mind?

maybe u mean PAAPA like 'original sin?' can u explain?

or maybe PAAPA u mean defilement of mind..

@blue_ego "Original Sin" is more of an Abrahamic Concept so I am not aware of it. Human Birth doesnot have a starting point. LIke Maya. Maya is Eternal besides Brahman. But Maya upon an Individual is not eternal. Why? Because an Individual can enlighten (exit Maya) oneself and so becomes Brahman, but the influence of Maya still continues on others. To answer your question, Brahman is INFINITE, with INFINITE possibilities. The opposite of being INFINITE is to be an INDIVIDUAL. How is that possible? . Out of infinite possibilities there is also one possibility of Brahman to witness maya as an ..

@blue_ego Cont ....
Individual. That individual cannot witness existence as a CUMMULATIVE being but only from a single perspective, like Love, affection, taste, touch, and more. You cannot taste something that is in someone else's mouth. Like in the movie Indiana Jones Crystal Skill, the Alien skulls are interlinked and act as single consciousness theory, but we don't.

@blue_ego Cont ..
So our Individualness is to witness all polarities (Love and Hate) that is not possible for a Cumulative consciousness. Rather we entangle ourselves into Maya and create Causality (Cause and Effect). This Cause and effect that creates DushKarma (negative karma leading to Hate and Hurt) is called Paapa (the opposite is Punya). This cycle of rebirth is called Samsara. For Brahman, there is no polarity, no good-bad, beauty-ugly. Brahman is pure, whole & infinite (our true nature). But in the darkness of Maya we think a rope is a snake (our own imaginations becomes our enemy)
